# Matching layers with different projections

Tags: coordinate-system, layers

I have two layers with the following projections:

```
Monte Mario IT1
UTM*
```

Anyhow, I followed the instructions (open the project, set the projection, select on the fly projection, load the layers but no way, the two layers does not match each other.

I could only obtain the result of picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzuA5.jpg) where in red are the transport flows, in blue the transport network.

The crs of the two layers are:

> red--> +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1500000 +y_0=0
>   +ellps=intl +towgs84=-104.1,-49.1,-9.9,0.971,-2.917,0.714,-11.68 +units=m +no_defs blue--> +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=0.9996 +x_0=500053 +y_0=-3999820 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-87,-98,-121,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs

If I set one of the layer with the same CRS as the other, the two networks becomes very far from each others (see picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFklQ.jpg))

Which do you think might be the problem?

[image: in red transport flows in blue the transport network]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The first data layer is, as you said, using Italy Zone 1 / West zone based on Monte Mario geographic coordinate reference system. The second data layer's +proj definition looks like UTM* / UTMRER aka TM Emilia-Romagna (ID = 5659) in the [EPSG Geodetic Parameter Dataset](http://www.epsg-registry.org). Although I'm on the subcommittee that maintains the Dataset, I was on leave when this coordinate reference system was added, and I'm finding the emails about it a little confusing. Because it's listed as being on Monte Mario, and the offsets look like a GeoCRS / datum issue, try these on the 2nd data layer:

1. Change the +towgs84 parameter to use the same values as the first layer (Monte Mario to WGS84) - EDIT: I think this option will work; see below.
2. Omit it completely

to see if the data layers will overlay better.

I found an [online translator](http://geoportale.regione.emilia-romagna.it/it/services/servizi%20tecnici/servizio-di-conversione/cts). If you convert a WGS84 coordinate pair to UTMRER (aka UTM*) and to Monte Mario Zone 1 / West, the coordinates differ only by the differences in the false easting and false northing values so both must have undergone a WGS84-to-Monte Mario conversion.

Input:
longitude = 10.0E
latitude = 44.0N

Results: 
UTMRER
East: 580255.2 North: 872556.1

Monte Mario Italy 1
East: 1580202.2 North: 4872376.1

East: 1580202.2 - 580255.2 + 53.0 = 1000000.0
North: 4872376.1 - 872556.1 + 180.0 = 4000000.0